# Why does `aws organizations list-roots` return a list instead of a single value?

Tags: aws-organizations

The AWS CLI `aws organizations list-roots` [returns a list](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/organizations/list-roots.html).

But given an AWS Account/login, it can only belong to 0 or 1 `AWS Organization`, right? Why did it return a list then (is there ever going be 2 or more items)?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's for forward-compatibility. In the future, AWS Organizations might support several roots, and then the API would be prepared for that.